# Missing bibliography citation not indicated in the bibtex log

Tags: bibtex

The bibtex log in texstudio tells me that " process ended normally ", however the citation JEC04 is represented in the pdf as "??". After inspection of the bibliography with Jabref, I noticed that I cannot find a key JEC04. In the bbl file it is not either.

I remember to get error messages when a citation was missing. What is happening here? Please guide to get proper error messages.

Comment: Check the .blg-file.

Comment: Sorry for the noise: the citation was not called with `\cite` but with a `\ref` which could not work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by an error in the input, as noted.